# How to show a word from the specified result

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble displaying words on the screen. I want result 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 then it is Fail and 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 it is true but I am not expert family. Someone help me please? Sorry if it's hard for you to understand because I use google translate. Here is my code

```js
let images = ["dice-01.svg",
"dice-02.svg",
"dice-03.svg",
"dice-04.svg",
"dice-05.svg",
"dice-06.svg"];
let dice = document.querySelectorAll("img");

function roll(){
    dice.forEach(function(die){
        die.classList.add("shake");
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        dice.forEach(function(die){
            die.classList.remove("shake");
        });
        let dieOneValue = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
        let dieTwoValue = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
        let dieTthreeValue = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
        console.log(dieOneValue,dieTwoValue);
        document.querySelector("#die-1").setAttribute("src", images[dieOneValue]);
        document.querySelector("#die-2").setAttribute("src", images[dieTwoValue]);
        document.querySelector("#die-3").setAttribute("src", images[dieTthreeValue]);
        document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML = "Your roll is " + ( (dieOneValue +1) + (dieTwoValue + 1)  + (dieTthreeValue + 1) );
    },
    1000
    );
}
roll();
```

```html
<div id="die-1"></div>
<div id="die-2"></div>
<div id="die-3"></div>
<div id="total"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating an array `rollResults` to contain the results of rolling each die.

We can then get the total score, using Array.reduce() to add the roll results together.

We would then output the individual die rolls along with the total and whether the roll was successful (e.g. if it was > 10):

```js
let images = [
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Dice-1.svg',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Dice-2.svg',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Dice-3.svg',
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Dice-4.svg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Dice-5.svg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/Dice-6.svg"
];

let dice = document.querySelectorAll("img");

function getDieResult() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}

function roll(){
    dice.forEach(function(die){
        die.classList.add("shake");
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        dice.forEach(function(die){
            die.classList.remove("shake");
        });
        let rollResults = Array.from({ length: dice.length }, (v,k) => getDieResult());
        let total = rollResults.reduce((total, roll) => total + roll);
        rollResults.forEach((result, idx) => {
            document.querySelector(`#die-${idx+1}`).setAttribute("src", images[result - 1]);
        })
        const success = (total > 10) ? "True": "False"
        document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML = "<br>Your roll is " + rollResults.join(", ")  + "<br> Total = " + total;
        document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML += "<br>Success = " + success;
    },
    250
    );
}
roll();
```

```html
<img id='die-1' width='50px'>
<img id='die-2' width='50px'>
<img id='die-3' width='50px'>

<div id='total'></div>
<br>
<button onclick='roll()'>Roll the dice!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m67mA.png) it appears (& hence assumed) that the objective is to show each of the individual die-roll. Instead, the numbers are getting added and rendered.

Please replace this:

```
document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML = "Your roll is " + ( (dieOneValue +1) + (dieTwoValue + 1)  + (dieTthreeValue + 1) );
```

With this:

```
document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML = "Your roll is " + (dieOneValue +1) + ', ' + (dieTwoValue + 1) + ', '  + (dieTthreeValue + 1);
```

Or, as suggested by DBS in comment below, we may use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this:

```
document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML = `Your roll is $(dieOneValue +1), $(dieTwoValue + 1), $(dieTthreeValue + 1)`;
```

Either of the above methods would introduce a `,` ('comma') between each die-roll result. If 'comma' is not desired, you may use space.

Also: in case the objective is to display 'fail' if the total is 1, 2, ...10 and 'true' if the total is 11, 12, ... 18, then try this:

```
document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML = `Your roll is ${(dieOneValue + dieTwoValue + dieTthreeValue + 3) < 11 ? 'fail' : 'true'}`;
```

Comment: Alternatively, [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are a great way to avoid using JS's multi-use `+` operator for string concatenation.

Comment: So, that would mean something like so: ` `Your roll is ${dieOneValue + 1}, ${dieTwoValue + 1}, ${dieTthreeValue + 1}` `

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what I mean, I don't want to separate each number but change the number. For example image is number 13 but I don't want to show number 13 but it is true :
"I want result 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 then it is Fail and 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 it is true"

Comment: I've just now edited the answer to cover this. Please look at the last section that starts with: 'Also: in case the objective is to display fail...'

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sum up the values and use that

```
const dieSum = (dieOneValue +1) + (dieTwoValue + 1)  + (dieTthreeValue + 1);
let result = (dieSum > 10); // true if <=10 or false if >=11
```

you can instead use this result in order to put whatever you want in the UI

```
document.querySelector("#total").innerHTML = dieSum > 10 ? "Pass" : "Fail"
```